# Return list<unsigned char*> from C++ to Java using JNI

Tags: java, c++, list, java-native-interface

I have the following JNI method,

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_projlib_DeserializeBuffer
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jbyteArray inBufferData)
```

I have created a list of `unsigned char*` and filling it using some data extracted from the `inBufferData` in my C++ code

```
list<unsigned char*> returnBuffer
```

I want to return the `returnBuffer` to my Java code, where it will be a List of byte array, `List<byte[]>`.

Please tell me how to pass the list of unsigned char* via a `jobject` through JNI and then get it in Java for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to do that directly. You will have to instantiate an instance of the needed Java list implementation (since `List` is an interface) in C++, put it in a `jobject` and then add `jbytearray` items to it from your list and then return the list.

**EXAMPLE**

Since I do not have a working JNI environment, this snippet is only illustrational (feel free to edit it when you get it working), but what you need could be achieved by this:

```
jclass arrayListClass = env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList"); // Find ArrayList class
jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(arrayListClass, "<init>", "()V"); // Find ArrayList constructor
jobject arrayList = env->NewObject(arrayListClass, constructor); // Create new ArrayList instance
jmethodID add = env->GetMethodID(arrayListClass, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z"); // Find the ArrayList::add method
jbyteArray item =env->NewByteArray(10); // Instantiate a new byte[]
env->CallBooleanMethod(arrayList, add, item); // Add the byte[] to the ArrayList
```

Comment: I am very new to C++, can you share some snippets?

Comment: @AnkitG I added a snippet but since I do not have a working JNI environment to test it on it is only illustrational, feel free to provide feedback or edit it.

Comment: @AnkitG I updated the snippet, the signature for the `add` method was wrong and it caused Java exception.

Comment: Thanks! Had one clarification. the data I want to return is not a ByteArray, it is a `list<unsigned char*> returnBuffer` in C++ and in the Java world it will be a `ByteArray`. From your code snippet, I will simply remove the line, `jbyteArray item =env->NewByteArray(10);` and in place of item, put my list/vector object. Let me know if that is a correct approach

Comment: @AnkitG In your question you mentioned `List<byte[]>` which seems correct. `list<unsigned char*> ` is a list of pointers to arrays - so unless you have chosen the wrong container it is not the same as `byte[]`. How many items are in your list? If multiple then how do you hope to represent multiple arrays with one `byte[]`?